# JAVA JFrames : Spacebar resets my game

Tags: java, swing, focus, jframe, cardlayout

So I have made a game where I would use cardlayouts to transition between frames.
However, every time I adjust the volume using my task bar then go back to my game, if I press SPACEBAR (which is my fire button) the game would go back to my first frame which is the HOME FRAME.

Why does this problem occur? I heard it has something to with "focusable" but im not to sure what that means.

My JFrame is set up like typical JFrames:

```
public class testAngles {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Angle Tests");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    movements m = new movements();
    frame.add(m);
    frame.addKeyListener(m);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
     }
  }
```

If anyone can help; Id greatly appreciate it :]

Comment: Pressing the space bar when something is focussed clicks buttons and checks or clears check boxes. Do you have something like that that the user might unwittingly focus on and that would change to the home frame?

Comment: In the all my panels, there is an option to go back to mainframe (except for my shop panel)

So pressing spacebar would automatically act if I pressed HOME?

Comment: Right. If this is a `JButton`, you might want to call `setFocusable(false)` on it, to prevent it being 'clicked' with the space bar.

Answer (score 3):

you have look at [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), then is simple and possible this one, for example (based on 3.HFOE's codes, thank you), rest could be to block value `setEnabled` for `JButtons` for first and last of `Cards`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class OnTheFlyImageTest {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel cardPanel;
    private CardLayout cardLayout;
    private JFrame frame;

    public OnTheFlyImageTest() {
        JPanel cp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        cp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        cardLayout = new CardLayout(5, 5);
        cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        cp.add(cardPanel);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {// Create random panels for testing.
            String name = "ImagePanel" + (i + 1);
            String image = (i & 1) == 0 ? "foo.gif" : "bar.gif";
            Color clr = (i & 1) == 0 ? Color.red : Color.blue;
            ImagePanel imgPanel = new ImagePanel(name, image, clr);
            cardPanel.add(imgPanel, name);
            cardLayout.addLayoutComponent(imgPanel, name);
        }
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 5, 5));
        JButton prevButton = new JButton("< Previous");
        prevButton.setActionCommand("Previous");
        prevButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.previous(cardPanel);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(prevButton);
        JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next >");
        nextButton.setActionCommand("Next");
        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.next(cardPanel);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(nextButton);
        JPanel temp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        temp.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        cp.add(temp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame = new JFrame("CardLayout and KeyBindings");
        frame.add(cp);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Test");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        setKeyBindings();
    }

    private void setKeyBindings() {
        frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), "clickTAB");
        frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("clickTAB", new AbstractAction() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "ImagePanel" + 1);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new OnTheFlyImageTest();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String imgString;
    private JLabel imgLabel;

    public ImagePanel(String name, String imgString, Color backGround) {
        setName(name);
        this.imgString = imgString;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground((backGround));
        // Ensure size is correct even before any image is loaded.
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            System.err.println(getName() + ": Loading and adding image");
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgString);
            imgLabel = new JLabel(icon);
            add(imgLabel);
        }
        super.setVisible(visible);
        if (!visible) { // Do after super.setVisible() so image doesn't "disappear".
            System.err.println(getName() + ": Removing image");
            if (imgLabel != null) { // Before display, this will be null
                remove(imgLabel);
                imgLabel = null; // Hint to GC that component/image can be collected.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So using Keybindings I could make it so when Im not operating within the frame (or the whole program in general), all my JButtons or setEnbale(false)?